# RASA slot setting using Tracker object

Tags: python, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa, nlu

Hi am trying to set slots using tracker object from inside custom action submit method.

```
    def submit(
        self,
        dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
        tracker: Tracker,
        domain: Dict[Text, Any],
    ) -> List[EventType]:
        tracker.slots["sample"] = value
        print(tracker.get_slot("sample"))
        dispatcher.utter_message("action is submitted")
        return []
```

this is the submit method of FirstAction and when I submit the slot inside this action method is getting setting but after I try to use the slot inside another Action the output is getting as None. I know when we send the return type of the submit as

```
    return [SlotSet("sample", value)}
```

the slot is getting set but when i try with tracker.slots["sample"] = value the slot value not persisting between the actions, I am writing a function with parameter as tracker so I need a way to set slot using tracker object or any solution to set slot from one helper function, So is there any way to persiste tracker.slots[key] = value in between actions?

Comment: I don't think that such a method exists. The only way to persist slots is by returning the `SlotSet` event at the end of the custom action. Can't you helper function that you call from within your custom action return a list of `SlotSet` events, which you then return in the custom action?

Comment: Thanks @tabergma, I am planning to call the helper function in backgroud thread so won't have to wait for the helper function return the control for my submit method, parrellaly I can load the tracker.